# Programmatically identify what SQL Server stored procedures are actually using a specific parameter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a SQL Server database (it's 2012 but could be 2008) with thousands of stored procedures.

I would like to programmatically know which stored procedure are receiving a specific parameter `companyid` but are NOT really  using it inside their queries.

So the 2 goals of this project are:

1. Identify what stored procedures do NOT receive the parameter `companyid`
2. Identify those stored procedures that DO expect the parameter `companyid` but that are not really using it within their code

I am envisioning to either write some TSQL or write an app in C# in order to complete the task - either suggestion would work.

So I'm hoping to hear from you guys what would be the best way to achieve so?

Thanks in advance

==========================================================
BASED ON BOTH SUGGESTIONS, THE SOLUTION IS THE FOLLOWING:

```
SELECT  Specific_Name,  
        ((len(ROUTINE_DEFINITION) - len(replace(ROUTINE_DEFINITION, '@companyid', '')))/ 10) as COUNT,  
    ROUTINE_DEFINITION  
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES  
WHERE   ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%@companyid%'  
ORDER BY 2, 1
```

Note: dividing by 10 the string replacement will give you the count of instances of that specific string within the body. 1 means it's only the parameter, 2 or more means it's used in the body.

Thank you both !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could make it sound simple.

Look at `ROUTINE_DEFINITION` field of

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
```

This basically gives u the body of the sp, fn, vw.

Answer (score 1):

Your first goal may be achieved with this

```
SELECT proce.name FROM sys.procedures proce 
INNER JOIN sys.procedures params ON proce .object_id=params.object_id
WHERE params.name='@companyid'
```

For second goal you can try this

```
SELECT proce.name from sys.procedures proce 
INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules modules on proce.object_id=modules.object_id
WHERE definition like '%@companyid%'
```

Comment: The 1st one is not working, as it returns empty if I use the WHERE clause. If I actually put the params.name on the SELECT, it gives me the same exact name as the proce.name